# Contar cuantas veces aparece una palabra en un archivo

Tags: python

Quiero contar cuantas veces aparece la palabra "hola" en un documento de texto.

```
a = open("archivo.txt")
b = "hola"

c = a.count(b)
print (c)
```

Y al ejecutar me sale:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Lo que quiero obtener es simplemente el numero de veces que está la variable **b** en el archivo **a**.

Comment: 'a' es un archivo. Para obtener su contenido debes usar alguna función como `read()` o un `for line in a:` y buscar dentro del contenido retornado.

Comment: Puedes hacer `a = open("archivo.txt").read().split()` para que `a` sea una lista que contiene las palabras del archivo. De ese modo ya te funcionaría el `a.count(b)`.

Comment: sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado con el siguiente código:

```
    a = open(r"archivo.txt", 'r')
    b = a.read()
    count = b.count("hola")
    print (count)
```